# Defining sqrt as type int in C?

Tags: c

So in c I'm trying to make a for loop that goes up to the square root of a number, 
but I need to define that square root as type int since the control statement can't have double types.

Basically what I did is define `int1` as type `int`, and then have `int1=sqrt(n);`.

However, the compiler isn't accepting it. Help?
Here's my entire code (it's an algorithm for Eratosthene's sieve)

http://pastebin.com/V6cHqj4F

Comment: Are you familiar with type-casting? (http://www.aui.ma/personal/~O.Iraqi/csc1401/casting.htm)

Comment: @ruakh: actually a better answer than the current ones, as you point to reasons for the situation. You should make it an answer.

Comment: Don't make us go somewhere else to see your code; post it here.  If the problem is truly as you describe, you can reproduce it with a far smaller piece of code than that!  However the expression with the implicit cast is entirely valid, though ill-advised, so your problem is elsewhere.  If the "*compiler isn't accepting it*", add the compiler error message or build log - that is what compiler diagnostic information is for!

Comment: @ruakh:  Are *you* familiar with *implicit casts*?  I don't think that is his problem.  Until the question includes the code, I am not about to follow the link to find out.

Comment: @Clifford: If I had thought that that was his problem, I wouldn't have needed to ask if he was familiar with it! I was trying to figure out what he does and doesn't understand about the subject, because of his statement that "the control statement can't have double types". The `int1=sqrt(n)` approach doesn't seem to be necessary, at least not for the given reason.

Comment: @ruakh: Fair point, not much about this question really holds up to much scrutiny.  My point was merely that since the implicit cast is valid, the issue is not directly relevant to the question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anything wrong with that. Show us your errors and read them because for example I saw that you are using `j` in your loops and it's never declared. Also what this code should do in your opinion?

```
int n, primecap[n], int1, i;
n=50;
initArray(primecap[n]);
```

Your problem is that you don't know what you are writing.

Answer (score 3):

```
int int1 = sqrt(n);
```

This is perfectly valid in Standard C and your compiler should accept it.
Either you enabled some picky warning option in your compiler or the error is elsewhere in your program.

(I assume you included `math.h` and `n` is of arithmetic type.)

Comment: +1 for being the only one to point out that the cast is useless.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider

```
int int1 = (int)(lround(sqrt(n));
```

Note there are a couple of assumptions here regarding the types in play, but this should work for you.

Given the nature of the *sqrt()* function, you might even consider assigning the result of *lround()* into an unsized data type (i.e. *unsigned long*, etc.)

Comment: `int(...)` is not valid C syntax. Did you mean `(int)(...)`?

Comment: +1 for `lround()`. "round their argument to the nearest integer value, rounding halfway cases away from zero,"

Answer (score 1):

> So in c I'm trying to make a for loop that goes up to the square root of a number, but I need to define that square root as type int since the control statement can't have double types.

Nonsense, you can use any type in for and while loop constructs.

> define `int1` as type `int`, and then have `int1=sqrt(n);`.

That is perfectly OK.

> However, the compiler isn't accepting it

I tried your code on ideone, and apart from missing headers and undeclared identifiers(`j`, `primecap`), the compiler didin't complain (about *this particular* thing).

Answer (score 1):

If [this](http://pastebin.com/V6cHqj4F) is your code `int n, primecap[n], int1, i;` your problem could be `primecap[n]` because `n` is defined later on.

Comment: +1 It also requires support for C99 variable-length arrays, which is not a given for all compilers.  The use of the uninitialised variable `n` to dimension the array is never going to cause anything good to happen!

Answer (score 0):

If you really only want an integer:

```
int1 = (int) sqrt(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cast the result of `sqrt()` to an `int`:

```
int int1 = (int) sqrt(n);
```

Comment: Note that the int cast will round towards zero. Depending on your application, this may be exactly what you need, or you may need `int int1 = (int) ceil(sqrt(n));` instead.